# Possible solution for "Could not initialize class sun.awt.X11.XToolkit"?

Tags: android, exception

I am getting below error while designing layout for the Android app(unable to open the layout in Layout Editor window)

```
Could not initialize class sun.awt.X11.XToolkit
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
```

Here is Error Log window:

[image]

FYI, i have:

- Eclipse Indigo
- ADT to 15.0.1 (Version: 15.0.1.v201111031820-219398)
- Tried to select Target as Android SDK 2.2, 2.3, even 3.0 also, but no success.
- I have "compiler compliance level" as 1.6 (also have 1.7), i have tried to set 1.7 also but having no success.

Do you know the possible solution to this error?

### Update:

```
paresh@comp35:~$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_18"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.8.2) (6b18-1.8.2-4ubuntu2)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 16.0-b13, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Can you please tell us what is Xtoolkit a Google search tells that its related to developing GUI for desktop system so how its related to your android project

Comment: ADT is trying to draw the screen in the layout editor, and apparently it uses the native Java AWT toolkit for this and fails. X11Toolkit is the Unix X Window implementation of AWT.

Comment: @ingsaurabh i don't know about it, i just have updated Android ADT to 15.0.1 and JDK, and suddenly this error is being appeared.

Comment: In general, please cut-and-paste messages rather than screenshots :)

Comment: @PareshMayani how you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Not really, but try updating your Java SDK. 1.6.0_18 is ancient.

Comment: Thanx @Nikolay for your answer, but you know i am also having compiler compliance level to 1.7 also but still having no success even i tried to set it.

Comment: That has nothing to do with this, and Java 7 is not supported by ADT. Keep it at 1.6 and use the latest JDK 6.0 version to start Eclipse.

Comment: OK, get the latest Sun/Oracle Java SDK from their site. IcedTea, etc. often have issues. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html